# Expo av plays audio only from earpiece instead of speaker

Tags: react-native, audio, expo, expo-go

When I run `npx expo start` and run the application on my IOS device only plays audio from the earpiece instead of the speaker, any idea of why this is happening?

This is my code:

```
import { View, StyleSheet,Button } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {

  const [audioPermission, setAudioPermission] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simply get recording permission upon first render
    async function getPermission() {
      await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync().then((permission) => {
        console.log('Permission Granted: ' + permission.granted);
        setAudioPermission(permission.granted)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }

    // Call function to get permission
    getPermission()
  }, []);

  async function playSound() {
    try {
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true
      })
        const {sound} = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require('./assets/beep.mp3'));
        await sound.playAsync();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to play sound', error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title="play sound"
        onPress={playSound}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    borderRadius: 64,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});
```

I also try replacing to false the attributes inside the Audio.setAudioModeAsync like allowsRecordingIOS and playsInSilentModeIOS but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set allowsRecordingIOS to false.

Answer (score 0):

Set this, but not on the useEffect, it won't work there.
You need to put this line right before creating the Sound object:

`await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ allowsRecordingIOS: false });`

Like this:

```
await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({ allowsRecordingIOS: false });
const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
await soundObject.loadAsync({ uri:`data:audio/wav;base64,${audioDatabase64String}` });
await soundObject.playAsync();
```